# Pixelated mkv on vm (vlc)

Tags: windows-10, video, graphics-card, vlc-media-player, pixels

I have a simple installation of windows 10 pro on a vmware WS VM and I installed vlc on it.

All video files play smoothly with normal picture except for mkv files which play with pixlated picture. audio is OK.

I tried:

1- `tools>preferences>all>input/codecs` and set `file caching` to `6000ms`.
2- `tools>preferences>all>input/codecs` and set `hardware accelerated decoding` to `disabled` then to all other alternatives with no luck.

mkv files play normally on windows media player.

vlc codecs are the standard installation codecs.

Host video card: `NVIDIA Quadro 3000M`
VM video card: `VMware SVGA 3D`

**Any ideas other than using another player?**